# mySQL select which query evaluate by parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a query like this one:

```
SELECT IF(@param = 42, 'static', SELECT ... );
```

But it doesn't work because I can't insert a SELECT statement inside a IF(). My problem is that I can't do otherwise (use an if-then statement outside sql) because to "architecture restrictions".

Any solution to select if evaluate or not a query based to parameter value?

Comment: Is the second select static? In that case you can just move the `IF` inside the query. If `...` is `foo FROM bar`  you get `SELECT (case when @param = 42 then 'static' else foo end) FROM bar`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `select`:

```
select (case when @param = 42 then 'static' else date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') end)
```

Note that you are trying to mix two different types -- a datetime and string.  You should explicitly convert the datetime to a string, using your preferred format.

You can write this with `if()`.  `case` is slightly more general and the ANSI standard.

Comment: My fault. I need to run a generic query, not only a now(). It only was for a short example.

Comment: @Alvins . . . If you need the subquery, put it in parentheses.